# django template tags within tags? trying to cut down on template logic

Tags: django

right now I have my models like this...

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    x_foo1_y = models.CharField()
    x_foo2_y = models.CharField()
```

views...

```
somevar = myModel.objects.get(title='title')

if x:
    x = 'foo1'
else:
    x = 'foo2'
```

template...

```
{% if x == 'foo1' %}
{{ somevar.x_foo1_y }}
{% elif x == 'foo2' %}
{{ somevar.x_foo2_y }}
{% endif %}
```

what I want to do is add some logic to my view that defines foo1 or foo2 under certain circumstances and then my template could be cut down to be a lot easier to read...

```
{{ somevar.x_{{ x }}_y }}
```

But that doesn't work and I can't think of a way to make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call an arbitrary method of any object create a simple [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def call_method(obj, method_name, *args):
    method = getattr(obj, method_name)
    return method(*args)
```

And then call it in the template:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{# equivalent of `somevar.x_foo1_y()` #}
{% call_method somevar 'x_foo1_y' %}

{# equivalent of `somevar.x_foo1_y('test')` #}
{% call_method somevar 'x_foo1_y' 'test' %}

{# equivalent of `somevar.x_foo1_y(othervar)` #}
{% call_method somevar 'x_foo1_y' othervar %}

{# equivalent of `somevar.x_foo1_y()` if `method_name == 'x_foo1_y'` #}
{% call_method somevar method_name %}
```

And, at last, equivalent of your `{% if %}` expression:

```
{# make the `x_{{ x }}_y` method name #}
{% with 'x_'|add:x|add:"_y" as method_name %}
    {% call_method somebar method_name %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: hmm thanks for the answer, this looks promising but I would need to take in the title of the model field as an arg in order to do this because my models are actually more complicated than just x_foo1_y, they are more like z_foo1_y, x_foo1_some_stuff, x_foo1_other_stuff, etc. Given the variety of model variables, do you think this would still work?

Comment: You want to call any method of object with any argument?  Something like `{% call_method obj "x_foo1_some_stuff" obj.title %}`?

Comment: I read over that a bunch and i still cant quite grasp what youre asking me, but ithink the answer is yes. I also fixed a typo in my code, i want to be calling somevar from the template, not title

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what would `x_foo1_y` and `x_foo2_y` be, but I'm guessing you are generalising and asking how to handle situations *like this*. As such, I would suggest you use [custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/), which might help in reducing your template logic by delegating some of it. Template tags can do pretty much anything, so I believe you could move lots of logic like this.